# playorm connects only to localhost

Tags: cassandra, playorm, astyanax

If I try

```
cassandra-cli -h myhost.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I connect to it with no problems. By using astyanax, it also works.

However, in playOrm, if I set my host string to `myhost.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9160`, it complains I need to use a comma separated string with the host list. If I use `myhost.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9160,` or `myhost.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9160,myhost.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9160`, I get the following exception.

How should I set the connection string to connect to a remote host?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TokenRangeOfflineException: TokenRangeOfflineException: [host=myhost.compute-1.amazonaws.com(...):9160, latency=336(336), attempts=1] UnavailableException()
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.CursorKeysToRows.execute(CursorKeysToRows.java:157)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.CursorKeysToRows.loadCache(CursorKeysToRows.java:100)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.CursorKeysToRows.nextImpl(CursorKeysToRows.java:65)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.CursorRow.nextImpl(CursorRow.java:33)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.iter.AbstractCursor.next(AbstractCursor.java:10)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerImpl.find(BaseEntityManagerImpl.java:132)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerImpl.saveMetaData(BaseEntityManagerImpl.java:235)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:102)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstanceImpl(BootstrapImpl.java:64)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:35)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:57)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:52)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:45)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:24)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:39)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.TestUserDao.testFindAllUsers(TestUserDao.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TokenRangeOfflineException: TokenRangeOfflineException: [host=myhost.compute-1.amazonaws.com(....):9160, latency=336(336), attempts=1] UnavailableException()
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:165)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:27)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$1.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:52)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:229)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:457)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.CursorKeysToRows.execute(CursorKeysToRows.java:155)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: UnavailableException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:9722)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:613)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:597)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:463)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:460)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:55)
    ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is expecting a real cluster to run 2 or more nodes not a single node.  (sorry, was on thanksgiving vacation).  Do you need to connect to just a single node?

Also, the reason we have detection in there is so we do CL_ONE if you only have one node but we assumed probably incorrectly people would only use one node to play around with cassandra(ie. localhost).  We didn't think they would actually go live with just one node.  Do you need modifications?  If so, let us know and we can change that.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in release 1.4.2 which is available in Maven repo. Please try and let us know if you are still facing any issue.